# cannot bundle install ruby - freeze fetching https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ubuntu

I'm trying to `bundle install` in an Ubuntu 13.10 (virtual machine) an existing big project.

But I only got the:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
```

Still running for 15 minutes now.  I use rbenv and 2.1.0 version or ruby.
That works on my Mac computer.

I have Bundler version 1.5.2 on the Ubuntu and 1.5.1 on the mac.

I just read https://thoughtbot.com/blog/fetching-source-index-for-http-rubygems-org about the bundle install/compilation time... But I guess I have another problem. Any idea why it does that?

By the way, It's not the first time I try to bundle install on the Ubuntu, I shutdown the process the last time because it was like freeze for 15 minutes, but it started to install many gems.

Comment: It just started to install gems... almost 20 minutes with a i7 processor, 8Go ram. My god. Just hope I won't have any installation issue...

Comment: I think it may have been related to network issues with rubygems..

Comment: How can I be sure about that?

Comment: Actually I guess you're right, that could be a good explanation, because once the fetching freeze is done, it's not slow to install everything. So maybe there is a pool of user waiting to fetch and we have to wait our turn. Or whatever else.

Comment: Try converting "https" to "http"

Comment: Can you try changing `https` to `http` just for test? Yes, I know it's insecure, I just want to exclude problems related to ssl.

Comment: Hum, yeah but how? I just enter bundle install, nothing more.

Comment: Okay, just had to change in the top of Gemfile.

Comment: Maybe a little quicker but not really. I waited 1 minute before the "resolving dependencies", then 2 min to resolve them then around 4 minutes "doing nothing".

Comment: Try a bundle install with --verbose so you can see what's going on. Perhaps a network / firewall problem fetching the gems.

Comment: After four times (three errors, missing dependencies) it's done and I won't try again for the pleasure :p But the next one could ;)

Comment: Changing "https" to "http" in the top of the Gemfile was the workaround that worked for me.  Will have to do until the network issues on rubygems.org are fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No real answer to this question by now, looks like it could be a rubygems network issue, maybe too many requests/users.

No solution, maybe use http instead of https is faster, not sure.
Just wait. Sometimes 20 minutes.

*From @JosephK*

> Changing "https" to "http" in the top of the Gemfile was the workaround that worked for me. Will have to do until the network issues on rubygems.org are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding explanation to why we converting to http from https works.

If you run

```
bundle install --verbose
```

You get more information about the error. The error I got was that:

HTTP GET https://index.rubygems.org/versions
Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError: Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://index.rubygems.org/versions.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.

It seems like it's an SSL issue where rubygems.org might not have uptodate SSL or something. Therefore It cannot guarantee secure connection and hence converting to http (which is technically unsafe) works.